# Checkbox game not working

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I am trying to create a simple android game where 10 checkboxes appear randomly on the screen and you have to check all of them as fast as you can. Then all checkboxes are deleted. The first part of the code works, 10 checkboxes are created. But if I add the second part of the code it doesnt work at all, not even checkboxes appear and app freezes.

public void checkbox(View v) {
        CheckBox[] cb = new CheckBox[10];

```
    RelativeLayout r = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cb[i] = new CheckBox(this);
        CheckBox c =cb[i];
        int randy = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 1100 + 90);
        int randx = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 600);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(90, 90);
        params.leftMargin = randx;
        params.topMargin = randy;
        c.setId(i);
        r.addView(c, params);}  

    while (!checked(cb)){} //wait untill checked(cb)=true
    r.removeAllViews();

}
public boolean checked(CheckBox[] cb) { //returns true if all checkboxes are checked
boolean b = true;
    for (CheckBox c:cb)
    {
      if (!c.isChecked()){
          b=false;
      }
    }


    return b;

}
```

Edited code:

```
int CheckedCount = 0;
int j = 0;
CheckBox[] cb = new CheckBox[10];
Boolean[] checked = new Boolean[10];

public void checkbox(View v) {
    Arrays.fill(checked, Boolean.FALSE);
    RelativeLayout r = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
    for ( j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        cb[j] = new CheckBox(this);
        CheckBox c =cb[j];
        int randy = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 1100 + 90);
        int randx = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 600);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(90, 90);
        params.leftMargin = randx;
        params.topMargin = randy;
        c.setId(j); //id set for each checkbox
        c.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                //missing code

                boolean c =true;
                for (boolean d:checked){
                    if (!d){
                        c=false;
                    }
                }

                if (c) {
                    RelativeLayout r = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
                    r.removeAllViews();
                }
    /*           //old code
                CheckedCount++;
                if (CheckedCount == 10) {
             RelativeLayout r = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
                    for (int a= 0; a<10;a++){
                        CheckBox c = cb[i];
                        r.removeView(c);
                    }
                    r.removeAllViews();
                }*/
            }
        });
        r.addView(c, params);

    }

}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a while loop is not the correct way to determine changes in the UI. Instead, I suggest you to add a listener to `onCheckedChanged` event for each checkbox, and only then check the checkboxes' statuses (with a method such as 'checked').

Comment: It worked but only with one listener. How could I implement onCheckedChanged listener to make a listener for each checkbox?

Comment: You should add it in the loop in your method 'checkbox', and in the listener make a call to 'checked'.

Comment: I added edited code above. First I tried to do it with incrementing count each time a checkbox is checked (marked as //old code). It worked but the problem was that I could just check and uncheck a single checkbox 10 times. To solve that I did an array of false booleans. Each time a checkbox would be clicked a boolean in the array with same index as checkbox would be set to true. But the problem is that I don't know how to get an index of a checkbox that was checked in  listener method.

Comment: You don't have too. Actually, as I see it, your check method should check the status of each checkbox regardless of whether it was clicked or not. It's much easier than having activity variables that indicates statuses. Just check them all on each click.